# Alternative to AWS Organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-emr

I'm using AWS Educate with a EMR cluster and S3 bucket. I would need to share the instances of two different AWS Educate accounts, but with AWS Educate, AWS Organization is not compatible.  Is there other service or similar way that would allow you to share instances for Amazon Educate?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This is a list of alternatives. However, I'm not sure if it can help with amazon educate: https://www.g2.com/products/aws-organizations/competitors/alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the AWS Educate Starter Accounts are [very limited](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf).

A usual procedure to enable cross-account access to resources is through [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html). However, the AWS Educate Starter Account FAQ states:

> You can create users, but cannot associate login profile or access keys for them. ***Additional restrictions may apply**

It's not clear if you can create such IAM roles and allow other accounts to assume them. But you can check. Using IAM console its rather **easy to create a cross-account role**, thus you can verity that.

Alternatively can **ask AWS Educate support** for such possibility.